# Power BI measurement between fixed Date and calculated Date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm interested in creating a report comparing a before and after of two equivalent time periods.

The after period is looking at the days from a fixed date (1/10/20) to the most recent case in the tbl_Data table (in this case it is 92 days).

The before period would subtract the calculated 92 days from the fixed date (1/10/20).

I was able to get the days between part fairly easily using the following:

```
Days_Between = 
calculate(
    countrows(date_table),
    DATESBETWEEN(
        date_table[Date_field].[Date],
        date(2020,10,01),
        MAX(tbl_Data[Date Received])
    )
)
```

However I'm at odds on how to subtract this from the fixed date to get a date range I can filter on easily. Any pointers/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First, I would simplify your days calculation: `Days_Between = DATEDIFF(date(2020,10,01), MAX(tbl_Data[Date Received]), DAY )`. Then, I would simply subtract the result from the given date. `Start date = Date(2020, 10, 1) - [Days_Between]`